# Jaspersoft studio canvas size or image size problem

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to use image that would fit A4 size (21x29.7) inside studio.

Inside studio I have set size of the page to:

[image]

Imported image and inserted it into canvas also the same size:

[image]

Problem is that studio doesn't fit image to report area:

[image]

Why it doesn't correctly sets the image when I use fit both width and height and both sizes are the same?

Comment: Try to remove flag on "constrain proportions"

Comment: Did it and still result is the same. For some reason image isn't showing same size as studio canvas.